# Inserting New Row in existing GridView from Footer(Contains Dropdowns and + button)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a case in which I'm showing gridview which is binded with the datasource using linq.
in footerrow of GridView I have an option to select values from 2 dropdowns and click add button an on add button I'm adding data in DB and showing data from DB.
What actually i need is that on add button it must be added to the gridview. and if gridviewrowbound is empty the user select from footer and add.

I have another UPDATE Button,on update I want to save changes to DB

I tried DataTable but couldn't do it.